# SharePoint issues after account SID changed

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint, sid

I have a problem with SharePoint. Basically the SID of my Windows Account changed (not sure why, still investigating) and SharePoint simply doesn't know me anymore - I get access denied messages and the like.

Is there a supported way to change the SID on a SharePoint user? On a Test setup I successfully changed the tp_SystemID in the UserInfo tables, but that seems too much of a hack for now.

As changing my SID in Active Directory is not possible, I'm not really sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly use the [SID History](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679833(VS.85).aspx) attribute to add your old SID back to your account.  This is the technique used when migrating accounts between domains to prevent having to update NTFS or other permissions the account had.

I have never manually updated this field though (only have used ADMT).

For information on how to update this attribute, look at the Sidhist.vbs file in the Windows 2000 support tools.  You cannot have another account in the forest with this SID though.

Comment: Going to check that. The Histroy attribute contains my old, "correct" SID indeed, so I think it's unique (going to check the forest)